# Convert html to image in aws node server without frontend

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, html-to-pdf

I want to convert following HTML to PNG image in Node.

```
<html>
    <b>Bold text</b>
</html>
```

This HTML is, of course, an example. 
Right now my project is in a aws elastic beanstalk. I've tried using packages such as node-server-screenshot that do exactly what I want but only work locally.

Is there any way to do this in aws?

Comment: Sounds like the solution best for your example would be a  lambda function. Input would be the html string from (SQS, API Gateway, ELB, or S3) , output could either be image saved to s3 or response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a server-less stack and how to do just what you said. With the best practices.

https://svdgraaf.nl/2016/09/28/Serverless-Screenshot-Service-With-Lambda.html

Comment: The stack template link doesn't work anymore.https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/serverless-screenshots-service/template.yml